# getRealPath returning false (Image Intervention and Laravel 5.1)

Tags: php, laravel, image-processing, laravel-5.1, intervention

I'm having a problem while using the `getRealPath` function.

```
$file = Input::file('archivo');
$img = Image::make($file->getRealPath());
```

I'm getting this exception:

```
NotReadableException in AbstractDecoder.php line 302. Image Not Readable.
```

I tried printing the value for `$file->getRealPath()` with `dd()` function and it prints `false`. Also I tried using `dd(Input::hasFile( 'archivo' ))` and that returned me `true`.

I can't seem to find an answer, I have tried almost everything I think.

So basically I want to know 2 things:

1. Why is `getRealPath` returning me false and not the path?
2. How am I supposed to send the route to `Image::make()`, I keep getting the annoying exception mentioned before even replacing `getRealPath(),` and sending instead the route as `public_path()."routestring"`.

Comment: According to the documentation [`getRealPath`](http://php.net/manual/ro/splfileinfo.getrealpath.php) returns `false` when the file does not exit. Are you sure the file is uploaded correctly? What does `dump($file)` output?

Comment: Somehow the file isn't getting uploaded.  Check your php.ini and mae sure file_uploads is on, the tmp directory is accessible by your webserver and the upload_max_filesize is appropriate.  post_max_size might also have some effect

Comment: Hello, I noticed that the real problem was the `save()` function that wasn't working because the route I was trying to get wasn't correct, also, I avoided using `getRealPath()`, instead, it worked fine for me with the `public_path()` function. Thanks for your advices!